# Android graphview x values lower than previous values

Tags: android, android-studio, android-graphview

i want to draw x,y plot using android GraphView library, when i try this series i got and error, please help why that graph cant be draw 
my series and code like this :

```
double[] series1Numbers = {0.07, 0.066, 0.069, 0.077, 0.090, 0.106, 0.123, 0.142, 0.161, 0.180, 0.200 };
double[] series2Numbers = {0.08, 0.078, 0.094, 0.101, 0.108, 0.115, 0.122, 0.129, 0.136, 0.143, 0.150};

for (int i = 0; i < series1Numbers.length; i++){
    series.appendData(new DataPoint(series2Numbers[i], series1Numbers[i]), true, 20);
    Log.d("x,y : ", String.valueOf(series1Numbers[i]) + ", " + String.valueOf(series2Numbers[i]));
}

graph.addSeries(series);
```

here is my error :

```
11-20 02:56:45.285  18818-18818/com.example.fetimeh.timol E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fetimeh.timol, PID: 18818
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new x-value must be greater then the last value. x-values has to be ordered in ASC.
            at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries.appendData(BaseSeries.java:411)
            at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries.appendData(LineGraphSeries.java:646)
            at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries.appendData(BaseSeries.java:464)
            at com.example.fetimeh.timol.calc.tidakadakorelasi$1.onClick(tidakadakorelasi.java:126)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: _new x-value must be greater then the last value. x-values has to be ordered in ASC_
Just sort your array from smallest value to highest

Comment: if  i sort it the result will be different, is there any options ?

Answer (score 0):

you can not append data backwards. If you need to change past data points you have to reset the complete data.

For this use `resetData` instead of `appendData`. Notice to give all values as parameter and not only the new one.